# How to count the unique values in a sliding window?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say that we have a DataFrame that simply contains the outcome of tossing a coin N times.

```
    outcome
0     H
1     T
2     H
3     H
4     H
5     T
6     H
```

For our example, let's suppose that we'd like to examine a sliding window of 3 and we'd like to count how many times each window (order preserved) appeared in the dataset.

The sliding windows of 3 in the dataset are:

- H-T-H
- T-H-H
- H-H-H
- H-H-T
- H-T-H

So the value counts would be:

```
H-T-H 2
T-H-H 1
H-H-H 1
H-H-T 1
```

I have thought of concating 3 sliding rows to create the windows as a string representation and then doing a value counts there. Is that a valid approach? Or is there a more pandas-oriented way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is valid but might not be efficient for large arrays as string concatenation/aggregation is expensive.

You could use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) here to benefit from the boolean-like aspect of your data:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

a = swv(df['outcome'].eq('H'), 3)
vals, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True, axis=0)

out = pd.Series(counts, index=np.where(vals, 'H', 'T'))
```

output:

```
(T, H, H)    1
(H, T, H)    2
(H, H, T)    1
(H, H, H)    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
(data["outcome"]+"-"+data["outcome"].shift(1)+"-"+data["outcome"].shift(2)).dropna().value_counts()
```